# How can I let matlab cluster within matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cluster-analysis

I need to reconstruct individuals in 3D true space from two 2D images. Currently I can give series of frame pairs (left and right) to matlab. It then does the following:

1: find black pixels:
2: calculate a vector for each black pixel
3: search for crosspoints between vectors
4: create datapoint for each crosspoint

Since a bird is never the size of one pixel they are reconstructed as flat squares in 3D space. with X being width Y height and Z distance from the cameras.

I now need a way to reduce these disks to centralized single points by taking there mean. In order to do this I first need to cluster them.

the three individuals are arrangend on the corners of a  perfect square so: X= pdist(A) Y= linkage(X) Z= clust(Y) does not work, because you wil lose a corner of the square. I used the code below to generate 131 matrices. Each matrix tells you which point belongs to another. for example M{1}{1} tells you all points that belong to the same group as point one (those within a distance 0.2)

All the information to cluster is within these matrices but i need to do the following and I do not know how. I need Matlab to:

1. group the points in matrix 1 that are in the same group.
2. give those a cluster ID == 1
3. then go to the matrix of the first point that does not belong to the group (in this case 4) and do the same.

The code to generate te matrices is found below. an individual has a size of .2 and the coordinates of the centers are `[30,30,300] [30,30,600] [60,30,600] [X,Y,Z]`

```
[X,Y,Z] data:

[X] 29.8000
   29.9000
   30.0000
   30.1000
   30.2000
   59.8000
   59.9000
   60.0000
   60.1000
   60.2000
   29.8000
   29.9000
   30.0000
   30.1000
   30.2000



[Y]29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.8000
   29.9000
   29.9000
   29.9000
   29.9000
   29.9000


[Z]599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
  599.7336
```

dCell in this case is 1.

```
for k=1:length(dCell) 
    A{k}=[X{k},Y{k},Z{k}]; As{k}=sortrows(A{k}); 
end

for m=1:length(As{k}(:,1))

    B{k}{m}=As{k}(m)-As{k}(:,1);
    C{k}{m}=As{k}(m,2)-As{k}(:,2);
    E{k}{m}=As{k}(m,3)-As{k}(:,3);
    M{k}{m}=[B{k}{m},C{k}{m},E{k}{m}];   
end
```

The data needs to be in cell arrays becaus there will be dimension missmatches throughout.

Comment: are those clusters separated? What I mean: you have 131 data points which you used to compute 131 matrices which contain all datapoints which are within your level of acceptance for each point. Could it be, that you have points like e.g. [1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8] with a lvl of acceptance of 0.2. Then you would have in each matrix (except the corners) 3 entries. and you would get clusters which are allways shifted by 0.2. What I am getting at is that if you do as you said in your 3 points. It could be that you won't get all 131 datapoints into 3 clusters [continued...]

Comment: AND it could be that some datapoints are distributed in 2 clusters and not just part of one

Comment: Do `A`, `As`, `X` `Y` `Z`, `B`, `C`, `E`, `M` have to be cell arrays? It seems like you are storing single values in cell arrays for no reason. They could then just as well be matrices. That would make things a bit easier.

Comment: Could you post a few rows sample data, please.

Comment: No, update your question and make it complete. You should create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)